# Memory leak when load PDF into UIWebView

Tags: ios, pdf, memory-leaks, uiwebview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webView.delegate = self;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Abtretung" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

On the simulator it's ok but on devices have memory leak.
[image]

Comment: are you using arc or non-arc

Comment: @cdon arc. As you can see memory released, but need time. When pdf loading I get ReceiveMemoryWarning and some times crash.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I am facing the same issue when loading a 20 pages PDF